# Why does this error pops up, express not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, node-modules

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
```

This is the code I am trying to run. I am running into this error:

```
"ReferenceError: express is not defined at Object."
```

I am sure this is the right way to import the package. I am not using it anywhere else in the codebase.

I have tried the following things:

1. Deleting `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and running `npm install`
2. Tried using `yarn` inplace of `npm`

Comment: Log express to console to see what methods are available.

Comment: Are you sure your package.json contains `express`? Did you run `npm install` in the right directory (where also your package.json is in)?

Comment: You have to add express to your `package.json`. To do that just: `npm install --save express`

Comment: I resolved this error guys. The Global file search didn't show up any 'express' matching expressions. But I found its usages in a file, in some function were I was testing a block of code by going through some of the files.

I put the `const express = require("express");` import on top of that file to fix it.